# Azure speech pronunciation assessment for Spanish always gives high scores

Tags: azure-speech

I recently switched from Google to Azure for text to speech and speech to text, and I am thrilled, it is amazing! However, when trying to use the pronunciation assessment for Spanish, I find that no matter how badly I butcher the language, speaking with my worst Texas "Yo HABLO es-pan-yol" American accent, I always get word scores of 98-100. I am using the es-ES language code and getting very accurate text, it is only the pronunciation assessment that I have a problem with.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this tool just pretty much useless for assessing non-English language pronunciation? Or is it just Spanish? I really hope I just need to tweak something, in all other ways Azure has proved incredibly useful and performant.